# Twig loop through menu items

Tags: php, arrays, twig

The menu, which I am trying to loop through, looks like this:

```
"menu" => array(
        array(
            "title" => "Nieuws",
            "url" => "#"
        ),
        array(
            "title" => "Standen",
            "items" => array(
                array(
                    "title" => "Eredivisie",
                    "url" => "#"
                ),
                array(
                    "title" => "Topscorers",
                    "url" => "#"
                ),
                array(
                    "title" => "Assists",
                    "url" => "#"
                ),
                array(
                    "title" => "Kaarten",
                    "url" => "#"
                ),
            )
        ),
        array(
            "title" => "Kalender",
            "items" => array(
                array(
                    "title" => "Eredivisie1",
                    "url" => "#"
                ),
                array(
                    "title" => "Topscorers1",
                    "url" => "#"
                ),
                array(
                    "title" => "Assists1",
                    "url" => "#"
                ),
                array(
                    "title" => "Kaarten1",
                    "url" => "#"
                ),
            )
        ),
        array(
            "title" => "PSV",
            "url" => "#"
        ),
        array(
            "title" => "PSV Watchers",
            "url" => "#"
        ),
        array(
            "title" => "Transfers",
            "url" => "#"
        )
    )
)
```

If the menuitem in an array, it means it will appear like a dropdown menu.

Currently, I use this code:

```
        {% for menuitem in site.menu %}
            {% if menuitem.items is defined %}
                <li class="c-drop">
                    <a href="#">{{ menuitem.title }}</a>
                    <div class="c-drop-menu">
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            {% for items in menuitem %}

                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
             {% else %}
                <li><a href="{{ menuitem.url }}">{{ menuitem.title }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

If `menuitem` is an `array`, it shows `Array` with an error like "Array to string conversion".

How can I make this work, so I get the menu items and, if its an array, loop over it, but still get the menu item?

Do I need to change the array to make this work, or something else?

Expected menu result:

- Nieuws
- Standen (dropdown)
- Kalender (dropdown)
- PSV
- PSV Watchers
- Transfers

**Update**

Current code:

```
       {% for menuitem in site.menu %}
            {% if menuitem.items is defined %}
                <li class="c-drop">
                    <a href="#">{{ menuitem.title }}</a>
                    <div class="c-drop-menu">
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            {% for items in menuitem %}
                                <li><a href="{{ items.url }}">{{ items.title }}</a></li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
             {% else %}
                <li><a href="{{ menuitem.url }}">{{ menuitem.title }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vDE2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I made it work with `is defined` like this:

```
        {% for menuitem in site.menu %}
            {% if menuitem.items is defined %}
                <li class="c-drop">
                    <a href="#">{{ menuitem.title }}</a>
                    <div class="c-drop-menu">
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            {% for items in menuitem.items %}
                                <li><a href="{{ items.url }}">{{ items.title }}</a></li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
             {% else %}
                <li><a href="{{ menuitem.url }}">{{ menuitem.title }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Thanks @Matt Smeets for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to render the value inside the href, if the value is an array, this will throw an array to string conversion. It would be a better idea to [loop through the keys](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/keys.html) and if the value of the key is iterable render the key

```
{% for menuitem in site.menu|keys %}
{% if site.menu[menuitem] is iterable %}
    <li class="c-drop">
        <a href="#">{{ menuitem }}</a>
        <div class="c-drop-menu">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                {% for item in site.menu[menuitem] %}
                    <li><a href="#">{{ item }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
{% else %}
    <li>
        <a href="#">{{ site.menu[loop.index0] }}</a>
    </li>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With your code, the dropdown menu items appear in the right way, but the non-array menu items are appearing as numbers.

Comment: Aah, that is because when there is no value, the key as a value. I've *freehanded* an update for my answer,

Comment: Now, it doesn't show menu item "PSV" and "PSV Watcher". If I add a value after the last menu item ("Transfers") to the menu array, it appears right.

Comment: Please update your code in the post, and I'll quickly put it into a project to debug

Comment: I changed my array a bit. The only problem is that I dont know how to access the key while in the loop. Could you help me?